# How to create a resizable konva shape when user hovers

Tags: konvajs

I am working on konva js. I am working on an app that lets users create custom shapes. and after creation they can resize it by mouse, connect two shapes by a line. So far the feature drawing custom shape and their connecting by line is complete.

Now I want to show dots around the custom shape when user hovers on the custom shape just like this

[image: when user hovers]

P.S I have seen this from https://app.diagrams.net/. I want to build drawing app same like it.If someone can navigate me to the resources from where I can build drawing app like this, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to show/hide anchors for the shape.

It is up to you to choose how to implement anchors. It can be custom anchors like in https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Modify_Curves_with_Anchor_Points.htm or it can be `Konva.Transformer` https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html.

On `mouseenter` you can show anchors. Hiding anchors is a bit tricker for the demo I will hide anchors when mouse is too far away from the shape. We can't use `mouseleave` as is here, because it will trigger hide when we simply hover `Konva.Transformer`.

In the demo, try to hover the circle.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const shape = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green'
});
layer.add(shape);

const tr = new Konva.Transformer();
layer.add(tr);

// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254838/calculating-distance-between-a-point-and-a-rectangular-box-nearest-point
function getDistance(rect, p) {
  var dx = Math.max(rect.x - p.x, 0, p.x - (rect.x + rect.width));
  var dy = Math.max(rect.y - p.y, 0, p.y - (rect.y + rect.height));
  return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

shape.on('mouseenter', () => {
  tr.nodes([shape]);
});



stage.on('mousemove', () => {
  if (!tr.nodes().length) {
    return;
  }
  if (tr.isTransforming()) {
    return;
  }
  const rect = shape.getClientRect();
  const dist = getDistance(rect, stage.getPointerPosition());
  if (dist > 60) {
    tr.nodes([]);
  }
});

layer.draw();
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^8/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```